# Genymotion + CWAC Camera

Tags: android-camera, genymotion, commonsware-cwac

Has anyone gotten the CWAC Camera (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to work with a Genymotion emulator (http://www.genymotion.com/)?

I can't get the preview to actually start. It works fine on a regular device. Would be awesome if I could get it working for the sake of speeding up development.

Comment: I have never tried the library on any emulator, let alone Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the camera feature?

To do so you need to open the camera widget and then enable it as shown here:
[image]

Comment: Yep! That was the first thing I did.

Comment: What the standard camera app displays?

Comment: The camera app displays ok (it's a little finicky). In my app the best i can get it to do is take a solid green picture? The preview never shows up.

Comment: Same problem - I think the solution is somewhere in the DeviceProfile setting.